# Constant Buffering & Audio/Video Out of Sync RTMP Streaming

Tags: streaming, adobe, flash-media-server, flashmedialiveencoder

I am attempting to establish a high quality RTMP stream using Flash Media Live Encoder and Flash Media Server which is installed on my CentOS VPS Host. I am able to connect to the stream with the following url in the encoder: rtmp://myhost:1935/live/streamname (this is example).

I am using Flash Media Playback and embedding the following html for video playback:

```
<object width="640" height="480">
<param name="movie" value="http://fpdownload.adobe.com/strobe/FlashMediaPlayback.swf">    </param>
<param name="flashvars" value="src=rtmp%3A%2F%2Fmyhost%3A1935%2Flive%2Fstreamname&poster=http%3A%2F%2Fsquarestream.ca%2Fpics%2Fframe.jpg&autoPlay=true&streamType=live&optimizeInitialIndex=false"></param>
<param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param>
<embed src="http://fpdownload.adobe.com/strobe/FlashMediaPlayback.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" width="640" height="480" flashvars="src=rtmp%3A%2F%2Fmyhost%3A1935%2Flive%2Fstreamname&poster=http%3A%2F%2Fsquarestream.ca%2Fpics%2Fframe.jpg&autoPlay=true&streamType=live&optimizeInitialIndex=false"></embed></object>
```

The problem I am having is that the video is consistently buffering (approx every 5 seconds), followed by a sped up video playback and the audio and video is never in sync. From everything I have read, my encoder settings are fine:

25 FPS, 500 Kbps bitrate video, 128 kbps audio, I am on internet connection averaging 6 MBPS upload, my CPU/RAM usage never above 75% as Adobe suggests. I fear the issue is my hosting, but I am at a loss, I have tried every conceivable encoder setting, and as far as I know, FMS is setup correctly on host, and can verify stream connects in the admin console. Any suggestions would be helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: It could very well be your host. Are you trying to do this through a regular ol' consumer ISP, or through a hosting company that isn't going to try and throttle the crap out of your connections?

Comment: It is consumer ISP, but I've speedtested several times, my connection is definately acceptable. Can't speak for the host though, it's GoDaddy VPS, Linux CentOS 64bit. Should be ok?

Comment: When you speedtest you're only testing using HTTP or FTP usually, not RTMP. They may be throttling RTMP connections to keep people from abusing their upstream connections.